# Disable macro in open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Sometimes when I open a workbook, Excel asks me if I want to enable content and macros. At this time I have the choice not to enable macros or not.

But sometimes Excel considers a workbook trusted and I don't get this question. In these cases, when a workbook has been opened and macros have been enabled automatically, is there any way for me to disable macros in the workbook that is already open and running with macros?

Comment: Do you only get the message about enable content when you open files from the internet or your intranet (if it's poorly configured)?

Comment: I personally believe this question belongs to `Super User` as this has nothing to do with programming whatsoever.

Comment: @user3819867 I do believe this qualifies as relating to ["software tools commonly used by programmers"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the context of vba. I do see what you're saying, though.

Comment: Added as a comment as tonester has given a better answer - you could open in safe mode by holding Ctrl while Excel opens, or by using the command line excel.exe /s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no theoretical grounds to back this but I have just disabled macros on a *password protected* set of modules with the method below:

1. `Alt+F11` to open VBE
2. `Run` > `Design mode`

The header will now show `... [design]`.
Try triggering a known event-based macro to find out if it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the VBE open, you will be prompted with a pop-up whether you want to enable macros. If it is not open, you will just have the yellow security bar (2007 and later).

You can edit your trusted locations in File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Locations

The only way to disable macros after enabling them is to restart Excel.

Comment: The Trust Center also enables you to execute Macros always/never/only after asking - regardless of source location.